Is it possible to generate the same r-exam questions in two formats?
I am writing the final exam for my class, which will be published on the canvas learning platform using the r-exam QTI generation. The exam involves randomly generated elements and variations of each question. Because this is a high-stakes situation, I want to make sure both I and the TAs go through all the generated content and manually check it for accuracy.
However, the issue is that if I upload the question to canvas, the "edit preview" only shows the question stem, and it is impossible to expand it when there are more than 25 questions (see screenshot).

So then the only way to verify the questions would be to manually open each of them in edit mode, and risk modifying one in the process of doing so. (I find it rather easy to accidentally accept/unaccept one of the answer suggestions, for example.) For that reason, I'd rather be the only person who messes with the edit mode of the exam.
Ideally, I would like to generate the very same set of questions both as a canvas QTI and as a html or pdf. (I don't mind if the randomization works differently, just that there is the same stack of questions overall.) Is this possible?
Here is a MWE (based on the elasticity3.Rmd question):
library("exams")
exams2html("elasticity3.Rmd",n=3)
exams2pdf("elasticity3.Rmd",n=3)
exams2canvas("elasticity3.Rmd",n=3)

I'd like to modify it so that there is a common draw of three parameter sets, but then the three output formats are exactly identical. Is there a way to achieve that?

Source of the problem: Between exams2html()/exams2pdf() and exams2canvas() the details of the exam differ because exams2canvas() also randomly generates certain IDs used internally in the XML. I have to think whether we can easily avoid this.
Workaround: All exams2xyz() interfaces return a list of lists containing the information that was generated. It's a list of random replications (of length n) of exercises (depending on the number of files you used). Each exercise contains: $question, $questionlist, $solution, $solutionlist, $metainfo. You can optionally store this list in a .rds file if you set exams2xyz(..., rds = TRUE). Then you can subsequently also re-load this file and use it to inspect the exercises. (A little care is potentially needed with the supplementary files, this depends on the exams2xyz() format.)
Below I have written a function display_canvas() that loads the .rds file and wraps all its contents into a single .html file. Hopefully you can adapt it to your needs, if necessary. Note that it assumes that your exercises also provide a "Solution" section (and not just the exsolution tag) and include that in the .html. If you don't have that you might want display $metainfo$solution instead.
Example:
library("exams") ## version >= 2.4-1
set.seed(0)
exams2canvas(c("deriv.Rmd", "boxplots.Rmd", "scatterplot.Rmd"),
  n = 5, name = "demo", rds = TRUE)
unzip("demo.zip") ## unzip Canvas .zip, only needed for graphics etc.
display_canvas("demo.rds")

Note that for the supplements (like graphics etc.) to work correctly, I made a small tweak that necessitates installation of version 2.4-1 of the package.
display_canvas <- function(x)
{
  ## obtain exam list
  exm <- readRDS(x)
  m <- length(exm[[1L]]) ## number of exercises
  n <- length(exm)       ## number of random replications

  ## HTML head
  html <- c(
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">',
    '<html>',
    '<head>',
    sprintf('<title>%s</title>', x),
    '<style type="text/css">',
    'body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans;}',
    '</style>',
    '<meta charset="utf-8" />',
    '</head>',
    '<body>',
    sprintf('<h2>%s</h2>', x),
    '<ol>')

  
  ## HTML body with exercises
  for(j in 1L:m) {
    html <- c(html, '<li>', '<ol>')
    for(i in 1L:n) {
      html_body <- NULL
      html_body <- c(html_body, '<li>')
      html_body <- c(html_body, '<strong>Question</strong>', exm[[i]][[j]]$question, '<br/>')
      if(length(exm[[i]][[j]]$questionlist) & !is.null(exm[[i]][[j]]$questionlist)) {
        html_body <- c(html_body, '<ol type="a">')
        for(ql in exm[[i]][[j]]$questionlist) {
          if(!is.null(ql) & !is.na(ql))
            html_body <- c(html_body, '<li>', ql, '</li>')
        }
        html_body <- c(html_body, '</ol>', '<br/>')
      }
      if(length(exm[[i]][[j]]$solutionlist) > 0L || !is.null(exm[[i]][[j]]$solution)) {
        html_body <- c(html_body, '<strong>Solution</strong>', exm[[i]][[j]]$solution, '<br/>')
        html_body <- c(html_body, '<ol type="a">')
        for(sl in exm[[i]][[j]]$solutionlist)
          html_body <- c(html_body, '<li>', sl, '</li>')
        html_body <- c(html_body, '</ol>', '<br/>')
      }
      html_body <- c(html_body, '</li>')
      
      ## insert supplements
      sdir <- sprintf("supplements_%s_%s", i, j)
      if(file.exists("data") && sdir %in% list.files("data")) {
        sfiles <- list.files(file.path("data", sdir))
        for(f in sfiles) html_body <- gsub(f, file.path("data", sdir, f), html_body, fixed = TRUE)
      }
      
      html <- c(html, html_body)
    }
    html <- c(html, '</ol>', '</li>')
  }
  html <- c(html,
    '</ol>',
    '</body>',
    '</html>')

  ## display
  html_file <- gsub("\\.rds$", ".html", x)
  writeLines(html, html_file)
  browseURL(html_file)
  invisible(html_file)
}


Woah, thank you! I'll try it out next week and report back!

Great, thanks. And just fyi: I had some similar code lying around for the output of exams2openolat() which I just needed to tweak a little bit. The main difference is that Canvas (unlike OpenOlat) does not use Base64 encoding of the supplementary files so a couple of extra lines were needed here.

In case someone else wants to use this and only has the solution tag, I've added
if(length(exm[[i]][[j]]$metainfo) > 0L || !is.null(exm[[i]][[j]]$metainfo$solution)) {
        html_body <- c(html_body, '<strong>Solution Tag</strong>')
        html_body <- c(html_body, '<ol type="a">')
        html_body <- c(html_body, toString(exm[[i]][[j]]$metainfo$solution), '<br/>')
        html_body <- c(html_body, '</ol>', '<br/>')
      }

right after the if clause with the solutionslist, which seems to work.

Unfortunately, the pictures don't display on my end. The html file includes the link as <p><img src=\"lotteries.png\" width=\"600\" /></p> but the file is actually located in a subfolder data/supplements1 of the unzipped folder (same basename as the rds file).

Oh wait, I'm just now realizing that I've compiled this particular exam prior to updating the package... let me retry!
